# Gmail App doesn't allow zooming in for Apple devices?

Tags: ipad, gmail, font, iphone, zoom

This is what my Mom said. She is an Apple user and is the only Apple user in my immediate family. I can't help really help her because she is not very technoliterate, and she and I are in different countries.

She says she is using **iPhone 6 plus** and **iPad Mini**.

If so, how does one fix or get around this? Is there a setting to change? Is there an alternative app to use?

If not, did the iOS Gmail App have this problem before? Do old Apple devices have this problem on the iOS Gmail App?

Answer (score 2):

Pinch-to-zoom on an email works in Gmail's latest iOS app (version 4.4) and Apple's native iOS Mail app (tested as far back as iOS 6).

Maybe she does not know how to pinch-to-zoom?

Comment: Thanks aidanb.01 ^-^ Not an Apple user so no idea what those are. I'm just going to send to my mom

Comment: @BCLC If you put two fingers on the screen and keep moving the fingers closer together it will zoom out, and vice versa.

Comment: @Peanut oh there's a word for that? Lol. Well not all apps have that. SE app doesn't but SE mobile site does. Maybe mom doesn't have latest. Thanks ^-^

Comment: Mobile sites usually disable it. There should be a script that can re-enable it.

Answer (score 0):

That is somewhat incorrect.  Pinch Zoom works on some emails, not others.  It is mostly inconsistent. (And yes, I'm using Gmail App 4.4 on IOS 9.2.3 beta)

Most of the time, pinch zoom does nothing. On some Emails it does zoom the text.